# protege how to add a reference to another ontology

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I am tying to integrate my ontology with another ontologies. what i did is importing the ontologies in my protege, that works, but protege lists all the classes, which is normally. i am looking if there is a way in which i just the reference (uri) of these ontologies and then i can use them from their prefix.

ofc, i am building my ontology using owl2

i hope you help me

Comment: What do you mean? Do you just want to know what these various URIs are? Or you want to extract them and do something with them?

Comment: You don't need to import the ontologies in Protege, referencing the used classes and properties using there URIs is sufficient. But if you want to access the informations hold by these ontologies,  you have to import them

Answer (score 4):

If you want to completely reason and materialise facts based on terms relating to the referenced concept, then you will need to fully import the ontology that the referenced concept belongs.

e.g given an external ontology with the following statements:

```
ex:Person a owl:Class;
   rdfs:subClassOf ex:Agent.
```

If you reference this in your without importing:

```
ex2:Doctor a owl:Class;
   rdfs:subClassOf ex:Person.
```

and make the following statement:

```
ex2:Jack a ex2:Doctor.
```

an run it through a reasoner, then you will also materialise the following:

```
ex2:Jack a ex:Person.
```

But not the following:

```
ex2:Jack a ex:Agent.
```

To materialise the latter, you will need to import the ontology with all the statements about ex:Person.